# Как хранить в одной таблице, ссылки на разные таблицы?

Tags: mysql

Допустим у меня есть таблицы для компонентов:
`simple_text_component`
`simple_image_component`
`media_gallery_component`

у каждой есть свои поля и свои записи.
Мне нужно создать еще одну таблицу `components`, в которой я буду хранить ссылки на записи из трех таблиц выше (их может быть и не три, а более в рамках роста проекта).

Идея в том, что я хочу в дальнейшем в одном запросе (или как можно оптимальнее) доставать по несколько компонентов из `components`. Как можно это сделать? Либо как спроектировать структуру таблиц удовлетворяющей решению такой задачи?
Пока в голову приходит что-то такое: хранить в таблице `components` id, тип компонента (строка, соответствует имени таблицы), далее делать запрос который извлечет все необходимые строки из `components`, потом на основе этих данных формировать запрос чтоб забрать все необходимые данные по каждому из компонентов, потом это маппить в необходимый формат и отдавай в контроллер. Выходит что будет два запроса.

Но такой вариант мне не очень нравится, предложите свое решение.

Comment: С приемлемой скоростью выборки - никак=) или через хранимки, но всеравно будет 2 запроса =)

Comment: https://habr.com/post/193380/

Comment: а у этих компонентов вообще что нибудь общее есть ? почему они лежат в 3 таблицах ?

Comment: @Mike у них  могут быть общие некоторые поля, программно  все создаваемые компоненты наследуются от абстрактного компонента, в котором собственно и описано несколько полей

Comment: классическим вариантом с точки зрения БД является создание общей таблицы, с общими полями, на которую и идет ссылка. что бы у всех объектов было общее пространство id. А вот уже уникальные поля каждого типа выносятся в отдельные таблицы, связанные один-к-одному с основной. при выборке тупо делается left join всех трех таблиц сразу, в условиях on при этом задается явное условие на тип объекта что бы лишнее не пыталось клеится